# FusionPBX: Ring Group with external phone numbers?

Tags: fusionpbx

I want to define a Ring Group that, when called, rings one extension and one external number (mobile phone). What is the best way to achieve that?

Right now only the extension is called. So just entering an external number in the Destination field does not work, the logs say

`[NOTICE] switch_cpp.cpp:1376 [ring groups][call forward all] user_exists id <mobileno> <domainname>`

and later

`[DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:3865 Originate Resulted in Error Cause: 27 [DESTINATION_OUT_OF_ORDER]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will check all calls using the dialplan to see if the destination is a local number for an external number it should say user_exists false every time.

This [DESTINATION_OUT_OF_ORDER] indicates that it may not have found a matching outbound route that matches the number of digits of the external phone number. Or it may mean that your carrier rejected the call maybe didn't like the caller ID that was sent. Easiest thing to try is attempt it with an outbound rout to different carrier.

In case you weren't aware FusionPBX 4.4 was release on 5 April 2018. Instructions to upgrade are post on docs.fusionpbx.com. Search term upgrade (version upgrade).

Comment: Upgrading to 4.4 not only worked flawlessly but also fixed my problem. Thank you very much, @Mark Crane